# after scaling still not able to calculate exact width and height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

i am moving image above another images the image goes at correct positions if not applying any type of scaling but if i apply scaling it will never goes at correct position.possibly width and height is changed

this is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/j53Vy/3/)

```
$( "#location-default-dropdown" ).change(function() {
    var selection = $(this).val();
    $obj = $('#dragable');
    var MainImgwidth = $("#backgroundImg").width();
    var MainImgheight = $("#backgroundImg").height();

    var objWidth = $obj.width();
    var objHeight = $obj.height();
    //var objWidth =  $obj[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    //var objHeight = $obj[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;



    var left = 0;
    var top = 0;

    if(selection == "TopLeft")
    {
        left = 0;
        top = 0;
    }
    else if(selection == "TopCenter")
    {

        left = (MainImgwidth/2) - (objWidth/2);
    }
    else if(selection == "TopRight")
    {

        left = MainImgwidth - objWidth;
    }
    else if(selection == "CenterLeft")
    {

        top = ((MainImgheight/2) - (objHeight/2));
    }
    else if(selection == "Center")
    {

        left = ((MainImgwidth/2) - (objWidth/2));
        top = (MainImgheight/2) - (objHeight/2);
    }
    else if(selection == "CenterRight")
    {

        left = MainImgwidth - objWidth;
        top = (MainImgheight/2) - (objHeight/2); 
    }
    else if(selection == "BottomLeft")
    {

        top = MainImgheight -objHeight;

    }
    else if(selection == "BottomCenter")
    {

        top = MainImgheight -objHeight;
        left = (MainImgwidth/2) - (objWidth/2);
    }
    else if(selection == "BottomRight")
    {

        top = MainImgheight - objHeight;
        left = MainImgwidth - objWidth;
    }

   $obj.css({'left':left+'px','top':top+'px'});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, that behaviour is correct. When something is transform:scale'd... it keeps it's normal width, height and position. This is great when, for instance you need a group of elements to have hover states that allow them to be scaled, and not affect elements around them.

Look at the hover states on this site I built; http://playaz.co.uk

If the hover states on those elements DID actually change the real width and height, instead of transform:scale; all of the other elements would get pushed around (unless of course they were positioned absolutely, which they don't need).

The solution is to just change the width and height of your image. to "2.2x" scale your image, try something like this:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).css('width',$(this).outerWidth() * 2.2); 
});
```

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADxw7/